# How to a formula in a Text value cell to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database dump of data I need to regularly format.  I'm trying to make a macro for this and am about 90% there.... The data dump is in a CSV elsewhere.  My macro is in a workbook (Toolwb) and contains a couple macros, a look up table sheet(LookUpSheet), and a sheet with some formulas on it(FormulaSheet).

I'm coming across an issue with my formula that I am copying from my FormulaSheet that uses `VLOOKUP` on my LookUpSheet.  Since I am running the code on a different workbook, I need to copy the formula over with the reference to Toolwb in it... And from what I can tell, Toolwb does not like formulas that specify Toolwk in the formula. It just edits them out and then breaks when the vba copies it over to the data dump.  So to get around this I changed the cell to be Text type instead of general.  Perfect! Copies over great.... But... I can't seem to get the formula to "refresh" once its in data dump cell.  I have to open the cell and hit enter for it to refresh and evaluate the data.

I've tried changing the cell General after pasting it and then set it to auto calculate.  I've also tried the formula refresh buttons.  What am I missing?

I would just as happily paste this from vba instead of a cell, but I'm having a hard time getting the quotes in syntax.

```
=RIGHT(VLOOKUP(VALUE(CONCATENATE(B2,".",IF(LEN(C2)<2,CONCATENATE("0",C2),C2))),'[Toolwb]LookUpSheet'!$C$2:$D$4419,2,TRUE),LEN(VLOOKUP(VALUE(CONCATENATE(B2,".",IF(LEN(C2)<2,CONCATENATE("0",C2),C2))),'[Toolwb.xlsm]LookUpSheet'!$C$2:$D$4419,2,TRUE))-6)
```

Comment: Have you tried in VBA `newWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Formula = formulaWorkbook.Sheets("FormulaSheet").Formula`?

Comment: THIS! This totally worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ricardo A solved this for me in a comment.

"Have you tried in VBA newWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Formula = formulaWorkbook.Sheets("FormulaSheet").Formula"

Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

- `"."` can be replaced with `CHAR(46)`.
- `CONCATENATE(0,C2)` is the same as `CONCATENATE("0",C2)`. The result will still be a string with a leading zero.
- `.Address(External:=True)` will produce a fully qualified workbook/worksheet/range reference as an address string including any necessary punctuation.
- I'm a little unclear on why `$C$2:$D$4419` needs to be specified instead of `$C:$D`.
- `IF(LEN(C2)<2,CONCATENATE("0",C2),C2)` is simpler as `RIGHT("00"&C2, 2)`

Code:

```
dim Toolwb as workbook, Toolws as worksheet, Toolrng as range

set Toolwb = workbooks("some workbook")
set Toolws = Toolwb.worksheets("LookUpSheet")
set Toolrng = Toolws.Range("C2:D4419")

Range("A1").Formula = _
  "=RIGHT(VLOOKUP(VALUE(CONCATENATE(B2, CHAR(46), RIGHT(""00""&C2, 2))), " & Toolrng.Address(External:=True) & ", 2, TRUE), LEN(VLOOKUP(VALUE(CONCATENATE(B2, CHAR(46), RIGHT(""00""&C2, 2))), " & Toolrng.Address(External:=True) & ", 2, TRUE))-6)"
```

I haven't tested that but it looks right.

You might also try this adaptation using REPLACE that removes the first 6 characters and effectively cuts your formula in half.

```
Range("A1").Formula = _
  "=REPLACE(VLOOKUP(VALUE(CONCATENATE(B2, CHAR(46), RIGHT(""00""&C2, 2))), " & Toolrng.Address(External:=True) & ", 2, TRUE), 1, 6, """")"
```